# Joining and organizing JSON object structure by combining like names

Tags: r, json, list, lapply

I have a list of unique JSON objects (assigned as json_object) all with similar structures that looks like this

```
{
  "WREF": {
    "PSME": {
      "sbt": {
        "upr":   68.34,
        "lwr":   3.02 
      }
    } 
  },
  "WREF": {
    "TSHE": {
      "mbt": {
        "upr":   39.425,
        "lwr":   -6.855 
      }
    } 
  },
  "WREF": {
    "PSME": {
      "mbt": {
        "upr":   119.82,
        "lwr":   16.02 
      }
    } 
  },
  "ABBY": {
    "PSME": {
      "sbt": {
        "upr":   84.42,
        "lwr":   9.02 
      }
    } 
  },
  "ABBY": {
    "TSHE": {
      "sbt": {
        "upr":   39.05,
        "lwr":   2.01 
      }
    } 
  },
  "ABBY": {
    "TSHE": {
      "mbt": {
        "upr":   69.35,
        "lwr":   4.07 
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

And I am trying to reorganize/restructure them into something more organized like this:

```
{
  "WREF": {
    "PSME": {
      "sbt": {
        "upr":   68.34,
        "lwr":   3.02 
      },
      "mbt": {
        "upr":   119.82,
        "lwr":   16.02 
      }
    },
    "TSHE": {
      "mbt": {
        "upr":   39.425,
        "lwr":   -6.855 
      }
    }  
  },
  "ABBY": {
    "PSME": {
      "sbt": {
        "upr":   84.42,
        "lwr":   9.02 
      }
    },
    "TSHE": {
      "sbt": {
        "upr":   39.05,
        "lwr":   2.01 
      },
      "mbt": {
        "upr":   69.35,
        "lwr":   4.07 
      }
    }  
  },
}
```

Im currently using this bit of code to do it however it only seems to put together the highest levels of the JSON like WREF and ABBY and not merging the PSME's and the TSHE's or anything that's a lower level in the JSON structure.

```
#loop through each object
lapply( X = seq( 2, length( json_object), 1), FUN = function( x){
      #if its the second object
      if( x == 2){
        #check if the first objects name matches and join
        if( names( json_object[[ 1]]) %in% names( json_object[[ x]])){
          final_object <<- Map( c, json_object[[1]], json_object[[ x]])
        } else{
          final_object <<-  c( json_object[[ 1]], json_object[[ x]])
        }
      } else{   #if not the second object
        #check if there are any matching names 
        if( names( json_object[[ x]]) %in% names( final_object)){
          #join matching names
          final_object[ names( json_object[[ x]])] <<- Map( c, final_object[ names( json_object[[ x]])],
                                                          json_object[[ x]]
                                                          )
        } else{ #if not, just join
          final_object <<- c( final_object, json_object[[ x]])
        }
        
      }
    })
```

The final object in this case comes out like this:

```
{
  "WREF": {
    "PSME": {
      "sbt": {
        "upr":   68.34,
        "lwr":   3.02 
      },
    },
    "PSME": {
      "mbt": {
        "upr":   119.82,
        "lwr":   16.02 
      }
    },
    "TSHE": {
      "mbt": {
        "upr":   39.425,
        "lwr":   -6.855 
      }
    }  
  },
  "ABBY": {
    "PSME": {
      "sbt": {
        "upr":   84.42,
        "lwr":   9.02 
      }
    },
    "TSHE": {
      "sbt": {
        "upr":   39.05,
        "lwr":   2.01 
      }
    },
    "TSHE": {
      "mbt": {
        "upr":   69.35,
        "lwr":   4.07 
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Eventually I would like to do this with much more complex JSON structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, defining `txt1` as your first text/code block:

```r
json1 <- jsonlite::parse_json(txt1)
out1 <- lapply(
  split(json1, names(json1)),
  function(z) {
    y <- do.call(c, unname(z))
    lapply(split(y, names(y)),
           function(x) do.call(c, unname(x)))
  })

jsonlite::toJSON(out1, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

which produces

```r
{
  "ABBY": {
    "PSME": {
      "sbt": {
        "upr": 84.42,
        "lwr": 9.02
      }
    },
    "TSHE": {
      "sbt": {
        "upr": 39.05,
        "lwr": 2.01
      },
      "mbt": {
        "upr": 69.35,
        "lwr": 4.07
      }
    }
  },
  "WREF": {
    "PSME": {
      "sbt": {
        "upr": 68.34,
        "lwr": 3.02
      },
      "mbt": {
        "upr": 119.82,
        "lwr": 16.02
      }
    },
    "TSHE": {
      "mbt": {
        "upr": 39.425,
        "lwr": -6.855
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is currently hard-coded for two-levels-deep. If you need it to be arbitrary, then this recursive adaptation of the above works with this example; caveat emptor, I have not tested with other types of list-structures.

```r
func <- function(obj) {
  if (!is.list(obj)) return(obj)
  tmp1 <- lapply(split(obj, names(obj)),
                 function(z) do.call(c, unname(z)))
  lapply(tmp1, func)
}

out2 <- func(json1)
jsonlite::toJSON(out2, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

renders similar output as above, though due to the recursive nature, it does not ensure ordering of lists is preserved.

Comment: You might want to add the `auto_unbox = TRUE` parameter to the `toJSON` function.

Comment: Walleo, does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks @deschen, yes that was a missing final touch.

Comment: I also tried to do it with a tidyverse approach, but didn‘t even get the list into a structure tibble format. Do you have an idea how it could work?

Comment: Huh? Your input is text, your output is text, the intermediate structures are *not* trivially table/frame-like ... where do `tibble` and `tidyverse` come into this?

Comment: Sure. The direct way is, well, more direct. But being familiar with the tidyverse I try to use it where possible. So in this case the input could also be a data frame like structure that‘s then turned into a list which again is turned into a JSON object. I do that regularly for some APIs, but I embarrassed myself here a bit with not being able to even turn the input list into a tibble.

Comment: Sorry @deschen, I initially confused you for the OP. No, I don't know how to do this in a "tidy" way short of replacing `lapply` with `purrr::map` or such, a very superficial tidyversification for sure.

Comment: @r2evans Yes! this recursive function works wonderfully!